# Unity does not consistently provide reflection probe colors in surface shaders

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, fragment-shader

For some mysterious reason, only at certain camera positions/angles, a boilerplate surface shader does not properly return a color from `unity_SpecCube0`.  It either returns pure black, or pure white, depending on the camera's position and direction relative to the object.

```
Shader "Custom/Jank Reflections" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MainColor ("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Geometry" "RenderType"="Opaque"}

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainColor;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float3 worldRefl;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            // Set the albedo color based on the texture
            o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb * _MainColor.rgb;
            o.Specular = float4(o.Albedo.rgb, 1);

            //reflection
            half4 skyData0 = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEXCUBE(unity_SpecCube0, IN.worldRefl);
            half3 skyColor0 = skyData0; //DecodeHDR(skyData0, unity_SpecCube0_HDR);
            if (skyColor0.r == 0 && skyColor0.g == 0 && skyColor0.b == 0)
            {
                skyColor0 = half3(1, 0, 0); //proving it is just returning black
            }
            half3 reflectionColor = skyColor0;

            o.Albedo = reflectionColor;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

I have tried both with and without HDR decoding, and that simply always returns black.

The `IN.worldRefl` does appear to return appropriate values.

I presume the reflection flips between black and white on some objects and not others because it's something regarding the relative positioning between the camera and the object.  It is NOT that some objects never have reflections, and others do; only camera position/rotation determines which objects receive pure black or pure white reflections.

The reflection probe is definitely large enough to encompass all objects, and the camera.

From what I can see, proper reflection vectors are being provided.  I have used several different ways to calculate it, I have rendered them, I have even hardcoded orthogonal vectors to avoid calculation errors, and they all suffer with objects having pure black or white reflections.

I have tried Standard, PlinnPhong, and Lambert.  They all suffer the same way.

Interestingly, the shader does NOT result in pure black or white reflection colors in edit mode, ONLY in play mode, even when using the same reflection probes.

I have tested both HDR and non-HDR light probes, and they both suffer with pure black or white reflection colors.

The reflection probes are set to real-time.  I have tried, and more than one.

It doesn't appear to be a mesh normals issue, as this is occurring on basic built-in Unity cubes.

Strangely, it seems to only happen during playmode.  At editor time, it appears to always sample the reflection probe correctly.  In fact, it still occurs if I remove all cameras in the scene, and leave just one basic camera with no extra components.  The only time the reflections work is when I disable ALL cameras, forcing Unity to use the editor camera!

I have been stumped on this for quite some time, and cannot seem to find any rhyme or reason why.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: If what you see in the reflection is another reflexion that can appear black

Comment: @bolov Okay, that's interesting!  What are standard tactics to resolve that?  Perhaps detect if its black and fallback to a pregenerated cubemap?

Comment: So, new revelation upon creating a fallback cubemap: if there are any playmode cameras, it NEVER accurately retrieves the reflection color.  It's either black, as described originally, or white.  I didn't realize the white was actually a flat white, until now!